# How Fix Package name 'android.support.graphics.drawable' used in: com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

> AndroidManifest.xml Error:    Package name
>   'android.support.graphics.drawable' used in:
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0,
>   com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1ASl.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBf1S.jpg

An error happened after upgrade Android Studio 3.4
Already try change compileSdk to `27 / 27.1.1` but still same 
and already try to disable "vector-drawable" lib but still same
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.2.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.packacge.name"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 4
        versionName "Dev"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        //variant.getAssembleProvider()
        variant.outputs.all {
            outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

}

dependencies {

    configurations.all {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v13'
    }
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

..

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

..

Comment: I guess you tried to do a full clean/rebuild of a project?

Comment: already rebuild and try to invalidate cache and restart but still same

Comment: I am facing a similar problem :(. No issues when using gradle plugin 3.3.2 and gradle version and gradle 4.10.1. But after upgrading gradle plugin to 3.4.1 and gradle to 5.1, I got the same error :(. darn... let me know if you find a resolution to this issue? Googled and googled but this error still persists... sigh... maybe maven would be better than gradle in the long run?

Answer (score 0):

You should try this way

```
    implementation('com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0') {
            exclude group: 'android.support.graphics.drawable'
            exclude module: 'support-vector-drawable'
        }
```

Comment: @adityanurhadi try to add exclude module, at my side project build with your dependencies

Comment: thank you for your response, but still same error. its possible from gradle version ? cause before update no error

Comment: @adityanurhadi Did you have google dependency at the project level in gradle in the repository field.